# How to get html element id using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am need to get the id before and after html element of dropdown list on change. Please see blow source code.
When **Fund name** selected I need to get the **previous selected checkbox id or name ( Cash / Epf )** & **after selected checkbox id or name ( No.of Units Reedem / Amount Reedem / All units)**.
Thanks in advance.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('.units').change(function () {
                alert($(this).attr('id'));
                alert($(this).before().parent().parent().html());
                
            }); 
  });
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
     <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha256-MfvZlkHCEqatNoGiOXveE8FIwMzZg4W85qfrfIFBfYc= sha512-dTfge/zgoMYpP7QbHy4gWMEGsbsdZeCXz7irItjcC3sPUFtf0kuFbDz/ixG7ArTxmDjLXDmezHubeNikyKGVyQ==" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
  <body>
<div class="setup-content" id="form-3">
        <div id="repurchase">
            <div class="lblHead">REPURCHASE REQUEST</div>
            <div class="form-group">
                1.<input type="checkbox" name="Fm3CheckBoxList1[]" id="fm3chk11" value="CashPlan" class="singlecheckbox plan" /><label for="fm3chk11">Cash Plan</label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="Fm3CheckBoxList1[]" id="fm3chk12" value="EPFPlan" class="singlecheckbox plan" /><label for="fm3chk12">EPF Plan</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <label>Fund Name</label>
                    <select id="fundId" class="form-control drplst units"  AppendDataBoundItems="true">
                        <option Value=""></option>
                        <option Value="123">123</option>
                        <option Value="369">369</option>
                    </select>
                </div>                
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="Fm3CheckBoxList2[]" id="fm3chk21" value="No_OfUnitToRedeem" class="singlecheckbox" /><label for="fm3chk21">No. of Unit to Redeem</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="Fm3CheckBoxList2[]" id="fm3chk22" value="Amount_ToRedeem" class="singlecheckbox" /><label for="fm3chk22">Amount to Redeem</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="Fm3CheckBoxList2[]" id="fm3chk23" value="All_Units" class="singlecheckbox" /><label for="fm3chk23">All Units</label>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="Fm3TextBox2" runat="server" class="form-control" placeholder="AMOUNT"></asp:TextBox>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
 </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: `.before()` is for inserting something before the specified element, it doesn't make sense to call it with no argument. Do you mean `.prev()`?

Comment: The parent of the previous element is the same as the parent of the current element, so I don't see the point of using `.prev().parent()`. It's like saying "my brother's mother" instead of "my mother".

Comment: What if more than one of the checkboxes is checked? If they're mutually exclusive, you should probably use radio buttons instead of checkboxes.

Comment: @CnuVas Should your plans be mutually exclusive (Cash ***or*** EPF)?  Should your unit/amount/all selection be a mutually exclusive selection?  Perhaps radio buttons should be used here.

Comment: @CnuVas What are you actually asking?  Your choice of words for the question make it confusing.  I think you want to know is how to determine which plan was selected, and which redemption choice was made, at the time the fund DDL changes, correct?  I'm going to answer it with that in mind, assuming the semantic behavior dictates mutual exclusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your plans are mutually exclusive, you would want radio buttons to represent them, unless that `F3m...` indicates some JS framework that would turn appropriately decorated checkboxes into mutually exclusive selections.  Maybe you don't want them to be mutually exclusive.  If that's the case I'll update my answer.  Either way, you can use another attribute on the group of checkboxes to aggregate them all, such as `name`.  See my changes to the code snippet (below) for using `name` to find the selected plan.  You could assign all checkboxes in a particular group a name, class, or modify their IDs to include some base to use in a selector.  You could put them inside a container element (div) for easier reference, and then bind your inputs' events...

```
var lastPlanSelection = "none";
$('input[name=targetSet]').on('click', function() { lastPlanSelection = $(this).val(); });
```

---

Modifying your snippet to find the selected radio button...same principle could be applied to checkboxes using class attribute.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('.units').change(function () {
                var selectedPlan = $('input[name=plan]:checked');

                alert("Selected Plan: " + 
                    (selectedPlan.length === 1 ? selectedPlan.val() : "none"));
            }); 
  });
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
     <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha256-MfvZlkHCEqatNoGiOXveE8FIwMzZg4W85qfrfIFBfYc= sha512-dTfge/zgoMYpP7QbHy4gWMEGsbsdZeCXz7irItjcC3sPUFtf0kuFbDz/ixG7ArTxmDjLXDmezHubeNikyKGVyQ==" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
  <body>
<div class="setup-content" id="form-3">
        <div id="repurchase">
            <div class="lblHead">REPURCHASE REQUEST</div>
            <div class="form-group">
                1.<input type="radio" id="cashPlan" name="plan" value="Cash"><label for="cashPlan">Cash Plan</label><br/>
                  <input type="radio" id="epfPlan" name="plan" value="EPFPlan"><label for="epfPlan">EPF Plan</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <label>Fund Name</label>
                    <select id="fundId" class="form-control drplst units"  AppendDataBoundItems="true">
                        <option Value=""></option>
                        <option Value="123">123</option>
                        <option Value="369">369</option>
                    </select>
                </div>                
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="Fm3CheckBoxList2[]" id="fm3chk21" value="No_OfUnitToRedeem" class="singlecheckbox" /><label for="fm3chk21">No. of Unit to Redeem</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="Fm3CheckBoxList2[]" id="fm3chk22" value="Amount_ToRedeem" class="singlecheckbox" /><label for="fm3chk22">Amount to Redeem</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="Fm3CheckBoxList2[]" id="fm3chk23" value="All_Units" class="singlecheckbox" /><label for="fm3chk23">All Units</label>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="Fm3TextBox2" runat="server" class="form-control" placeholder="AMOUNT"></asp:TextBox>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
 </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.units').change(function () {
            alert($(this).closest('.form-group').prev().find('.singlecheckbox:checked').attr('id'));
            alert($(this).parent().next().find('.singlecheckbox:checked').attr('id'));

        }); 
});
```

This is working for single checked box, if more than one checkbox was chekced, you need to iterate that and doing something with that.